# @auth.requires_membership not working

Tags: web2py

Using web2py for my application I would like to include a login for registered users (the users are pre-registered by me through admin interface and are members of the group 'eap').
In my controller I have

```
#login for EAP parties
@auth.requires_membership('eap')
def eap():
    return locals()

def user():
    auth.settings.login_next = URL('eap')
    return dict(form=auth())
```

In my model I have

```
auth = Auth(db, host_names=myconf.get('host.names'), secure=True)
## create all tables needed by auth if not custom tables
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False)
```

When I use
'example.com/eap' I am referred to 
'example.com/user/login?_next=/eap' and the request to input username and password.
After providing those, I am ending up at 
'example.com/user/login?_next=/eap#', whereas I obviously wanted to access 'example.com/eap'

I am using the default 'layout.html' and 'user.html' provided by web2py.

I have read the documentation on Authentication and have been through several blogs..., any pointers on what to look into would be much appreciated!

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with `@auth.requires_membership()`, as you are not even getting past the login. When you submit the login credentials, do you get an "Invalid login" flash message (note, this may not appear if you are not using the default layout that comes with the scaffolding app)?

Comment: Many thanks Anthony - you are correct, it is not specific to @auth.requires_membership. I do not see an "Invalid login" message - I reckon that should appear with using the default layout.html and user.html (which I do use). It seems to "submit" the credentials but ends up at the url I mentioned above - do you reckon it to be a redirect issue?

Comment: Just re-checking again - during the course of the app, I have removed several web2py files, including web2py.js - probably I have broken the functionality here

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use @auth.requires_membership on the decorated action - turns out it works fine after having re-registered users in db auth_user through admin.